# When I write to the SharedPreferences, there seems to a mix between the stored Strings

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I'm writing a small application in which the user can write his name and it is stored in the preferences.

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString(getString(R.string.name), editText.getText().toString);
editor.commit();
```

The text of this editText is then set to the name. In another activity, I write in another string to the preferences, a number.
When I come back to the activity with the editText, the text reads the number that I have put in the preferences. They seemed to have mixed ... Do you know what I should do ?

In the first activity, here is the code :

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(getString(R.string.name_pref), name_et.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String name = preferences.getString(getString(R.string.name_pref), getString(R.string.empty));
    name_et.setText(name);
```

In the second activity, here is the code :

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString(getString(R.string.fgnum), random_number);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Could you explain your problem more precisely?

Comment: In the first activity, here is the code :
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

Comment: Post the code of how you are setting it in the other activity and how you are reading them here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure the resources `R.string.name` and `R.string.fgnum` have different values, If so, it's very strange problem. For simplicity try with some static pref keys like this:

```
editor.putString("KEY1", editText.getText().toString);
editor.commit();
```

and

```
editor.putString("KEY2", random_number); 
editor.commit();
```

And then check the result

Comment: Actually, the initial value with which they are defined in the XML code are the same, do you think that causes the problem ?

Comment: @LeoFillioux Yes, they must have different values

Comment: @LeoFillioux The first argument of `putString` is **KEY** and every key MUST be unique. That's it `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
editor.putString("YOUR_LABEL_TO_FIND_STRING", "THE_STRING_VALUE")
```

If, in your second activity, you also use the key **getString(R.string.name)**, it's normal... 
Change the key and no more mix !

Also, always use in your whole app :

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

> I write in another string to the preferences, a number. When I come back to the activity with the editText, the text reads the number that I have put in the preferences.

You are basically doing something like this:

```
String s = "edittextString";//first activity
s = "7"; //second activity. //second activity
```

You are overriding the value in your preference. So only the latest value is shown. You should use separate key for your first Activity and second activity if you want to use both the values.

Comment: But I write in the preferences using another string, and there is also another value which I write in the preferences, and it doesn't get mixed.

Comment: When you say another key, do you mean another string ?

Comment: @LeoFillioux in your xml check the values of R.string.name_pref and R.string.fgnum and make sure they are not the same.

Comment: In the first activity, I store the value if name_pref, and in the second I store the other value in fgnum.